# Probability distribution function and distribution function

Tags: probability, statistics

Is there a difference between the two?

For discrete variables: PMF and CDF exists. The CDF is what we call the distribution function

For continuous variables: PDF and CDF exist. The CDF is what we call the distribution function.

What is the probability distribution function then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDF is the “Cumulative Distribution Function” — some authors say “distribution function” as shorthand but it’s really the former that is correct.

A probability distribution function is the function that describes how much probability is assigned to various subsets of the range of a random variable. For continuous variables it often refers to the pdf, for discrete variables it is the pmf

Comment: Yes I know about the CDF. My question is about the **probability** distribution function, not distribution function which would be the CDF

Comment: @imbAF Ok — it’s the pmf or pdf then

Comment: so probability distribution function = pmf,pdf and distribution function=cdf,etc?

Comment: @imbAF yep — that the usual terminology

Comment: Ok thank you for the clarification. Usually people who teach these def. etc are pretty lazy. They assume that just because they understand them, the others can too and therefore they don't pay attention to what they say

Comment: @imbAF exactly!